# XHR failed loading: GET Works sometimes and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to submit a request to google places and retrieve the lat and long. I am using the code

```
let term = $("#getaddy").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+encodeURIComponent(term) +"&key=GOOGLEKEY",
    type: 'get',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.status === 'OK') {
            // Get the lat/lng from the response
            let lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            let lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
            console.log(lat);

        }
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        console.log("not sure what to ask for here to check issue");
    }
});
```

The confusing thing is I will get back XHR failed loading or XHR finished(it seems random). As much as I try changing things I can't see why it works or fails. Everytime I enter the url directly into the browser it returns the data correctly, even when it says its failed.

Does anyone know what is causing the failures, or what I should put in the console.log to help determine the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue. I was having randomly XHR failed loading or XHR finished. The problem was the definition of the button which triggers the function. I had defined html button without **type="button"** and this was refreshing page before getting response. I added type to definition and it stopped refreshing the page and my problem was solved.

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

This was the solution for me. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Heh this did it for me too, I had a button with type set to 'Submit', changed it to button type and the XHR request worked like a charm. Thank you!